# Error adding store through REST API to GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I have problem with adding raster layer to geoserver automatically. I need, that geoserver add layer without person job, only script action and i saw that it may be done with cURL REST API but, i can't do it.
In general, I have some GeoTIFF files and i want to published them at geoserver through the terminal. I do how [wrote DaveParillo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/programming-geoserver-2-0-2-to-add-a-raster-data-store-and-layer-without-the-ui). I can add workspace,

```
 curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<workspaces><name>geotiff</name></workspaces>' http://192.168.255.197:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces
```

answer

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.255.197...
* Connected to 192.168.255.197 (192.168.255.197) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 192.168.255.197:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 43
>
* upload completely sent off: 43 out of 43 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 14:15:53 GMT
< Location: http://192.168.255.197:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff
* Server Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8 is not blacklisted
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.255.197 left intact
```

but when i try add store i touch this error:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<coverageStore><name>fff</name><enabled>true</enabled><type>GeoTIFF</type><url>/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/avhrr_locale1e2.tif</url></coverageStore>' "http://192.168.255.197:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff/coveragestores?configure=all"
```

answer:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.255.197...
* Connected to 192.168.255.197 (192.168.255.197) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces/geotiff/coveragestores?configure=all     HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 192.168.255.197:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 155
>
* upload completely sent off: 155 out of 155 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 14:16:14 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
:Store must be part of a workspace
```

Geoserver log same error:

```
2015-12-10 17:15:53,801 INFO [catalog.rest] - POST workspace geotiff
2015-12-10 17:16:14,687 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'fff',    enabled
2015-12-10 17:16:14,688 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - :Store must be part of a   workspace
2015-12-10 17:16:14,688 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   Store must be part of a workspace
```

What's wrong?

Geoserver v.2.8.1.

Comment: It is known issue, I've also stumbled upon it some time before.
See [report on JIRA](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7161), it is still opened.

Comment: anyone can edit the documentation to fix this

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the workspace name when creating coverage store. In your case XML will look like this:

```
<coverageStore>
  <name>fff</name>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <type>GeoTIFF</type>
  <workspace>geotiff</workspace>
  <url>/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/avhrr_locale1e2.tif</url>
</coverageStore>
```