# What's the best way to serve a changing set of Geotiffs as a WMS layer?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have a set of geotiffs that will be continually updating and I'm trying to find the best way of automating this process. At any point in time, I want to be able to make a WMS request against a single layer name that returns the composite single jpeg etc. and I'd also like to be to constrain that WMS search using time fields. I am using the OpenGEO suite with Geoserver and a PostGres DB.

I envisaged having a folder on my server system that I would transfer each new geotiff as it comes in and probably running a curl command to somehow add that to the existing collection. Looking around, it was unclear what would be the best approach that would support this.

1. It seemed like I can use the Geoserver REST interface to add a Geotiff as a layer but it wasn't obvious if I could somehow keep on adding each new geotiff to this layer or if it was only for a 1:1 mapping of geotiff to layer name (but then maybe using a layer group and adding each layer to this group)?
2. Coverage stores - ([Programming Geoserver 2.0.2 to add a raster data store and layer without the UI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/programming-geoserver-2-0-2-to-add-a-raster-data-store-and-layer-without-the-ui)) Underdark's comment sounded promising but it was not obvious what the constraints are with using a coverage store (ongoing reading around on this one currently ;-) )
3. Somehow using the PostGRES to store the metadata etc. (and maybe a raster quicklook) but this approach seems more relevant for vector info rather than raster.

Currently my geotiffs are only about 35MB each but I'd like to extend this system to support multiMeg/Gig satellite imagery so I'd need to be able to support some form of pyramiding in the future so thoughts on expandability of the above challenge to support this functionality would be useful to hear (e.g. better to create multiple individual files for each pyramid level and assess which filename to access (expected to be more efficient for memory management??), OR creating a single composited pyramid file with 1x1, 2x2, etc. levels (or maybe 1x1 stays separate and the pyramid has 2x2, 4x4 etc. only))